# List items that contain a string value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a list of objects that has a string for phone number, I want to create a query to look for a list of objects that has any of the numbers.

here is the model:

```
public class ReportViewModel
    {
        public int QueueReportId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool Sent { get; set; }
        public DateTime Day { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

and I send a list of ReportViewModel to the view, is there a way to sort that list that is being sent to the view by phone number if the phone number is not an exact match?

for example, I would like to search on the list for objects that have a phone number that contains the area code 513 anywhere on the `public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }`

I know how to look for items with that are exactly the same, but not for something like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you familiar with the `string.Contains()` Method..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) method and pass an expression to check it in the `PhoneNumber` string property with the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) string method, for sample:

```
// get your list
List<ReportViewModel> reports = GetReports();

string areaCode = "513";

// check if any object has a phone value in any part of string
if (reports.Any(r => r.PhoneNumber.Contains(areaCode)))
{
   // contains the phone number
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to do some modifications to make it fit my code but this is what I needed. All of the other answers are correct too! but I needed to chose the one that was closer to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use LINQ's `Where`:

```
List<ReportViewModel> reports = //....

foreach(var report in reports.Where(r => r.PhoneNumber.Contains("513"))
{
    //do something for each report
}
```

Comment: This works also, I just needed to build a new list inside the foreach

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by something like :

```
 List<string> areaCode= new List<string>() { "somecode123", "somecode321", "somecode456", };
```

And you want to find a match of any item from areaCode list on the modular "ReportViewModel".

If yes then this should work :

```
var records = new List<ReportViewModel>;

var results = records.Where(q => areaCode.Any(t => q.PhoneNumber.Conatins(t)));
```

This should help, please match the bracket.

Comment: @RiquelmyMelara : You might wanna mark it as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If I undersatand your questions correctly `is there a way to sort that list that is being sent to the view by phone number if the phone number is not an exact match?` Here is how you can do it to sort the list if the phone number doesn't match in the list.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ....
    var reportsvm = GetReports();
    if (!reportsvm.Any(x => x.PhoneNumber.Contains("513")))
    {
         reportsvm = reportsvm.OrderBy(x => x.PhoneNumber).ToList();
         // reportsvm = reportsvm.OrderByDescending(x => x.PhoneNumber).ToList(); // if you want in descending order
    }

   return View(reportsvm);
}
```